# Colleting a neighborhood in foursquare

Tags: foursquare

im making a app in using the Foursquare API, using their API i can get some places in a neighborhood.

I'm using one like that:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore
?ll=40.7,-74
&limit=50
&venuePhotos=1
```

Using that API i can take 50 venues around my point, but how can I take more others venues like a second page of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "offset" parameter to query for subsequent pages of results. For example, to get the second page, you would supply "offset=50" to indicate skipping the first 50 results.